# Is there a way to launch a Lightning App in Lightning from Classic?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, salesforce-classic

I'm thinking of having something in Classic that both switches to Lightning and starts in a specific Lightning App. Perhaps all that is needed is an official, documented API that does the equivalent of what the "Switch to Lightning Experience" link does:

```
<a href="javascript:sfdcPage.handleSwitchToLightningClick(%27LightningExperiencePreferred%27,true,%27/ltng/switcher?destination=lex-campaign%27);" class="switch-to-lightning"><svg>...</svg>Switch to Lightning Experience</a>
```

with the Lightning App pre-selected as the default.

Is a URL link sufficient to switch e.g. from Classic:

```
https://java-drive-8200-dev-ed.cs18.my.salesforce.com
```

to Lightning:

```
https://java-drive-8200-dev-ed.lightning.force.com
```

Comment: I think you need suffix /ltng/switcher?destination=lex

Comment: /ltng/switcher?destination=classic to return back to classic

Comment: Have you tried using link https://java-drive-8200-dev-ed.cs18.my.salesforce.com/ltng/switcher?destination=lex and https://java-drive-8200-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/ltng/switcher?destination=classic ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `lightning.force.com/lightning` in a URL link should be enough to have the user's page opened in Lightning Experience (LEX).

In terms of opening a specific app, there's two ways that you can see mentioned in the [PageReference Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type) doc under "App".

> App that you’re navigating to. Pass either the **appId** or
> **appDeveloperName** to the appTarget.
>
> The appId is the DurableId field on the AppDefinition object.
>
> To form the appDeveloperName value, concatenate the app’s namespace
> with the developer name. To find the app’s developer name, navigate to
> the App Manager in Setup and look in the Developer Name column.
>
> For standard apps, the namespace is standard__. For custom apps, it’s
> c__. For managed packages, it’s the namespace registered for the
> package.

1. *appId* is the `DurableId` of the [AppDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_appdefinition.htm) you're interested in which makes the following link:

`yourDomainName.lightning.force.com/lightning/app/DurableId`

2. `DeveloperName` which requires adding a prefix depending on if it's a Standard App (`standard__`), custom (`c__`), or packaged (namespace).

`yourDomainName.lightning.force.com/lightning/app/standard__LightningSales`

`yourDomainName.lightning.force.com/lightning/app/c__CustomAppName`